# Check a modification expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Can we verify that the following expression will modify the Id of my user without executing it?

```
Expression<Func<User, User>> expression = user => new User { Id = 2 };

Func<User, User> update = expression.Compile();
User userReferent = new User();
User userTransform = update(new User());

return userReferent.Id != userTransform.Id;
```

Can we do something that looks like the following?

```
Expression<Func<User, User>> expression = user => new User { Id = 2 };

return expression.Contains(user => user.Id)
```

Comment: Why should you use an expression for that?

Comment: I want to use EFCore.BulkExtensions in my Repository pattern and I need to check that the developers don't pass anything in lambda expressions as a parameter of this api.I therefore wish to be able to validate them.

Comment: This should be something handled by business layer.

Comment: No, I don't want this to be the responsibility of the developers, but of the architecture. For example, I don't want it to change the tenant id, during a massive update operation

Comment: Implementing business logic in data layer isn't a good approach, that's just a tip

Comment: Preserving the tenant id is not a business rule, which is why I want the architecture to manage it. The tenant id is a technical identifier. My example in this post was bad.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I can check the expression avoiding to compile the expression.

```
Expression<Func<User, User>> expression = user => new User { TenantId = 2, Name = user.Name + "Test" };
Expression<Func<User, object>> searchMemberExpression = user => user.TenantId;

expression.Contains(searchMemberExpression) // return true

public static bool Contains<TEntity>(this Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> expression, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> searchExpression)
    where TEntity : class
{
    UnaryExpression unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)searchExpression.Body;
    MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;

    MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression = (MemberInitExpression)expression.Body;
    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<MemberBinding> bindings = memberInitExpression.Bindings;

    bool result = bindings.Any(binding => binding.Member == memberExpression.Member);

    return result;
}
```